# Finding the 19th derivative of $\frac{x-1}{e^x}$ using taylor series

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Full context: The problem is multiple choice and originally asks to find the 19th derivative which I prefer to do by Taylor Series. My method get's the answer (after plugging in $x=0$) but it is a bit unsatisfying since it relies on there being multiple choice options and I am wondering if there is a less multiple choice-y way to do the question under time pressure.

I took 
$$f(x)=e^{-x}(x-1)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}(-x)^{n+1}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}(-x)^{n}$$
A taylor series centered at zero. Then we can equate 
$$
\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}=a_n\Rightarrow \frac{f^{(19)}(0)}{19!}=\frac{1}{18!}+\frac{1}{19!}\Rightarrow f^{(19)}(0)=20
$$
Then plugging in, only one solution satisfies $f^{(19)}(0)=20$: $(20-x)e^{-x}$.

I am wondering: Is there a more sound way to find a closed form solution? I tend to not be great at looking for a pattern, especially under pressure, so if that is your method please explain how you go about seeing a pattern quickly after a couple of computations.

Comment: My previous (now deleted) comments were incorrect: I made a calculation mistake and misunderstood the question a bit; apologies. To answer the question: unfortunately, I dont think there is a great way to do this other than to 'recognize the pattern' after taking a few derivatives. That being said, it seems like such a question should only be asked in multiple choice format and if it is multiple choice, I think you used the best method for reasoning through it if you prefer not trying to guess at patterns. This seems like something that would be on the GRE for example which is multiple choice.

Comment: fair enough, thank you for clarifying. And that is where it came from :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this  maybe useful for you
$$y=e^{-x}(x-1)$$
$$y'=-e^{-x}(x-1)+e^{-x}=-y+e^{-x}$$
$$y''=-y'-e^{-x}=y-2e^{-x}$$
if you continue, you will get the following equation for nth derivative 
$$y^n=(-1)^{n}y+(-1)^{n+1}*n*e^{-x}$$

Comment: This is an excellent answer and exactly what I was looking for, a method for "seeing" the pattern

Answer (score 3):

Hint: By the quotient rule
\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= \frac{(1)e^{x} - e^x(x-1)}{e^{2x}}\\
&=e^{-x} - \frac{(x-1)}{e^x}\\
&=e^{-x} - f(x)
\end{align*}
If you want to be rigorous, you can use induction to finish this off! However, its clear from this point that

$$f^n(x) = (-1)^{n+1}ne^{-x} + (-1)^nf(x)$$
(which gives your answer for $n=19$).

Hope this helps.

Comment: this was also great, I am sorry I saw the other one first. Upvoted!